# Excel: what values are ignored by plots and formulas?

Tags: excel

I have data that in some rows may contain entries that I what to exclude from the analysis. If I use a string in these cells, e.g. `=""`, then I can pass the data into formulas and they work fine, but then plots interpret this data in a funny way and figures are displayed incorrectly. If I use `=NA()` then the plots work fine, but the formulas don't work. i.e. they also return `#N/A`.

What value can I use so that the formulas and plots work correctly?

Comment: Arguably, a formula returning `#N/A` *is* working correctly. After all, if you are e.g. missing the data for sales in November then you don't have enough information to calculate total sales for the year. There is no simple recipe for handling `NA`, but the function `ISNA()` together with things like `AVERAGEIF()` can be used to craft formulas that work as you might want. The same sort of problem occurs in R, and doubtless other computer stats packages. How to handle missing data is a problem for which there is no good, general solution.

Comment: Actually, Excel seems to handle missing values in both plots and formulas just fine (where by missing I mean an empty cell), so I would have thought that there is some special value, similar to `#N//A` (call it `#BLANK`), which would be treated as if it was truly blank cell. Alas, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `N/A` means "not available" which is just stat-speak for "missing". It is a way of being explicit that the value is actually missing from the data set. When you code it that way, you presumably *want* Excel to be conservative when dealing with it. Blank cells are typically treated as zeros in formulas, which is not always a principled thing to do.

Comment: @JohnColeman  As far as I can tell, most Excel function actually don't treat blank cells as 0. In fact, I don't think I have ever seen such treatment in any Excel function. Anyhow, it seem that `AGGERGATE()` function is the best / easiest way of dealing with this: it can be used to make some Excel function ignore `#N/A` and the plots will work with `#N/A` too I believe.